# How to convert webscraping into django api?

Tags: python, django, api, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape some data on two websites. I successfully scraped it. I also want to develop an API using this scraped data using Django. But when I try to display the scraped data in JSON format in Django. It only shows an empty list.  Below I attached my code snippets.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json
import time
data = []


def getURL(url):
    url = url.replace(' ', '-').lower()
    for char in url:
        if char in "?.!:;|/[]&()":
            url = url.replace(char, '-')
        if char == "'" or char == ",":
            url = url.replace(char, '')

    decodeUrl = re.sub(r'-+', '-', url)

    # check whether the URL is up or not

    parsedUrl = "http://www.tutorialbar.com/" + decodeUrl + "/"
    if requests.head(parsedUrl).status_code == 200:
        return parsedUrl


urls = ['https://www.discudemy.com/all', 'https://www.discudemy.com/all/2']
for url in urls:
    source = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html5lib')
    # print(soup)
    for content in soup.find_all('section', class_="card"):
        # print(content)
        try:
            language = content.label.text
            header = content.div.a.text
            day = content.find('span', class_="category").text
            i = content.find('div', class_="image")
            img = i.find('amp-img')['src']
            image = img.replace('240x135', '750x422')
            description = content.find('div', class_="description").text.lstrip()
            myURL = getURL(header)
            udemyURL = requests.get(myURL).text
            udemySoup = BeautifulSoup(udemyURL, 'html5lib')
            udemylink = udemySoup.find_all('a', class_="btn_offer_block re_track_btn")[0]["href"]
            entry = {
                'language': language,
                'header': header,
                'day': day,
                'image': image,
                'description': description,
                'courselink': udemylink,

            }
            data.append(entry)

            print()
        except Exception as e:
            continue

print(json.dumps(data))
print()
print(data)

def index(req):
    return render(req, 'index.html', {'courses': json.dumps(data)})
```

Below is my HTML file for displaying JSON data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UdemyCourses</title>
</head>
<body>
{{ courses }}
</body>
</html>
```

There is some delay in scraping data. I think it might be a problem. I don't know how to handle asynchronous programming in python. Is there any way to achieve it? I'm a beginner. Help me out. Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest to make a basic django app and get comfortable with the framework a little before you worry about implementing this service. I would get the data via ajax/xhr and display a loading bar in the meantime but you can take care of that once you are there.

Comment: your line `for url in urls:` isnt good. Write it like `for x in range(0,5): url =f'https://www.discudemy.com/all/{x}'` where 5 is the number of pages you could also get this value dynamically....

Comment: I know a django well.I don't want to store the datas in database.I just want to directly render it in html page.

Comment: wrap your bs4 code in a function. call that function in your view `def index(req):`. ỳou could write something like `data = my_function_name(parameters)` parameters is optional. you could add the url here or some input the user gave you. just return `data` in your context and thats it.

Comment: Thank you ..! It works. But it takes more than a minute to load. Is there any idea to load it faster. Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229957/discussion-between-hansthefranz-and-arun-balaji).